# Is it worth adding short circuit protection to a 5V string of WS2811 fairy lights?

Tags: safety

I'm making a control box to drive a string of 5V RGB fairy lights. Each RGB LED has a WS2811 driver chip. All the LED drivers are in parallel. The positive and negative leads along the length of the string each have a total resistance of about 1 Ohm. I have a 5V 10A switched mode power supply with overload protection.

I'm wondering whether there is much benefit from adding some protection against a short circuit in the string. Given the low supply voltage and relatively high resistance of the leads, the short circuit current would depend where the short occurred.

Would there be much benefit to adding a fuse or equivalent protection between the PSU and the string, in order to reduce the risk of the leads in the string overheating and creating a fire risk if a fault occurred?

[image: Similar light string]

Answer (score 1):

A 10 amp supply powering a flammable Christmas tree is a potential fire hazard in the event of a short, so yes you should install a fuse. This is doubly so if you are loading the supply well below capacity, which increases the odds that the power supply short circuit protection will not engage in the event of a short.

Make sure that the fuse is sized appropriate to the load. If that is 2 amps of LEDs, do not blindly install a 10 amp fuse. Use a 3 amp or so fuse in that case to be sure it cuts the circuit in the event that one of those (extremely cheaply made) lights burns up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are concerned with shorts that draw more than your load but less than the 10A of the PSU (more than 10A your PSU will cut out).  So, not exactly a short.  The odds of this happening are quite low. You can add a fuse but, other than that , I would leave it with the PSU and avoid any circuitry.

Comment: Exactly. I want to avoid the leads overheating and setting the Christmas tree on fire, but I don't know if it's a serious concern.

Comment: 5V at 10A is 50W. A 9W LED light is very bright, 50W will quickly blind you and melt all the LEDs. Are all the LEDs turned on at the same time? Then their current might be only 1A or less.

Comment: Ah, a Christmas tree.  So, you are kind-of concerned about safety.  If you were actually concerned, you would buy UL approved lights.  Your process is to hope your solution is safe. I'm out.

Comment: @GTElectronics Could you not have phrased your concerns as helpful advice rather than casting aspersions? Besides, the Christmas tree was just an example application; the point of the project is to build the controller (though the controller will not be UL approved either).

Comment: UL is not abut prevention of fire, it is about protection from insurance companies in the event of a fire.

Comment: I disagree, but I'll let you have your conspiracy theory.  My conspiracy theory is that conspiracy theories are loads of fun when there is no other fun to be had.